# Ресайз и перемещение окна pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Окно само отображается, но сворачивать, ресайзить и перемещать я его не могу. В чём может быть проблема?

Использую python 3.6.8.

Distributor ID: neon
Description:    KDE neon User Edition 5.14
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, у меня ваш пример работает и выполняет все действия, которые вы описали.

Comment: Я запускаю код, и у меня просто статичное серое окошко выходит, с которым ничего нельзя сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том ,что окно передвигается и ресайзится еще до его появления. Можно сделать два thread'a .
Но я просто приведу пример с кнопкой :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*


if __name__ =='__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QMainWindow()
    def moveIt():
        w.resize(250, 150)
        w.move(300, 300)
    button=QPushButton()
    button.setText("Do it!")
    button.clicked.connect(moveIt)
    w.setCentralWidget(button)

    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```